# problem to implement route forwarding method

Tags: minikube

I have developed one application using minikube and one pod. I am using IPVS mode here. The application works when I have used Masq forwarding methods. But it does not work for route forwarding methods. Should I need to configure anything when I am using route forwarding method?

Here I have attached IPVS list for masq and routing forwarding method.

```
    # ipvsadm  -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.96.0.1:443 wlc
  -> 147.214.68.51:8443           Masq    1      2          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Masq    1      0          0
TCP  10.108.116.175:5000 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  127.0.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  147.214.68.51:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  172.17.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Masq    1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:9153 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:9153              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:9153              Masq    1      0          0
UDP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Masq    1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Masq    1      0          0


  # ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.96.0.1:443 wlc
  -> 147.214.68.51:8443           Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.108.116.175:5000 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  127.0.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  147.214.68.51:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      3          0
TCP  172.17.0.1:32673 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.4:5000              Route   1      0          0
TCP  10.96.0.10:9153 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:9153              Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:9153              Route   1      0          0
UDP  10.96.0.10:53 wlc
  -> 172.17.0.2:53                Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.17.0.3:53                Route   1      0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got three suggestions for you:

1. Try to [debug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/proxy/ipvs#debug) and see if you meet all the prerequisites and things from the check list.
   Also, [here](http://www.iakovlev.org/index.html?p=1184) you can find a guide describing LVS-DR Cluster using the route forwarding method (Chapter 13).
2. Consider using [kube-router](https://www.kube-router.io/).

> Providing high performance is at the core of all the design choices
>   made in Kube-router. Be it the use of IPVS/LVS for service proxy or
>   the use of direct routing across the nodes for pod networking etc.

A documentation with guide can be found [here](https://www.kube-router.io/docs/).

3. If that don't help you'll need to provide more details regarding your configuration for us to work on.

Please let me know if that helped.